# Smash Up - Teddy Bears "Group Hug" Card

Tags: smash-up

"Group Hug" card in Teddy Bears Faction reads:

> Give one of your minions +1 power for each other minion at the same base until the end of the turn.

Player A (owner of Teddy Bear faction who is playing Group Hug) proceeds to play Group Hug on top of 1 of their 3 in-play minions on that base.  Player A thus has 2 other in-play minions at the time on that base (total of 3, the one on which Group Hug is played + 2 more).  The rest of the base looks like this:  Player B has 1 minion in play, Player C has 2 minions in play.

How many extra points does Player A garner from playing Group Hug:  3 or 5?  In other words, does Player A get to count only other players' minions as the +1 power, or does Player A also get to count their own "other minions" as extra points here?  It goes to how do you define "other minion"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

5.

By default, "minion" refers to any minion card on any base. Qualifiers such as "your", "each other player's" and "on the same base" are added to refer to subsets of those.

Since Group Hug uses neither qualifier "your" nor "each other player's", who controls the minion is not a consideration when counting the other minions on the base.

---

The game consistently uses "each other player's minions" to refer to minions you don't control. The lack of this qualifier indicates not just the minions others control are included.

For example, Compare *Ninja Master* and *Nukebot*.

> *Ninja Master*: You may destroy a minion on this base.
>
> *Nukebot*: ..., destroy each other player's minion on this base.

---

The game consistently uses "your" to refer to minions you control. The lack of this qualifier indicates not just the minions you control are included.

For example, Compare *Friendship is Power* and *Snow White*.

> *Friendship is Power*: Move one of your minions ...
>
> *Snow White*: Talent: Move a minion ...

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response.  There is no confusion about the use of "your."  The confusion is on the use of "each other minion."  I agree the answer is 5, but another player was disagreeing.  The argument was over whether "each other" means yours + others' (or just others') minions.

Comment: @ikegami The question was whether it counts yours at all, not if it counts only yours. In effect, the question was asking if it should be read as "each other player's minions." While I agree the answer is 5, you are focusing on the wrong end of things.

Comment: @Andrew, wow. Fixed.